# How do I perform a manual segue from within UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

Throughout my code it's been necessary for me to perform manual segues, it's been working great and I use this code.

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"createToCaseSegue" sender:Nil];
```

The problem is, wanting to press a button `Choose User` within a UITableViewCell and this is providing me errors.

[image: screenshot]

And the error.

[image: error]

I can understand why it's not working - I would need to call from the UIViewController to use `performSegueWithIdentifier`, but equally I don't know how to fix this.

I thought I'd try some fixes, so I tried to Ctrl-Drag an action into the ViewController file instead of the TableCell file, but it gave me Storyboard compilation errors (I guess this makes sense - if I have multiple cells, then do all the button instances refer to the one action?). I had also thought of programatically finding the superview, but apparently this method varies for iOS 7, so it sounds difficult.

Comment: You have a typo in the code anyway. Did you try to send the action back to the view controller.

Comment: Sorry, yeah there is a typo that I made during screenshotting. I've updated my question with extra content at the bottom (hopefully) relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add the "Choose User" button's action method (with `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:`) in cellForRowAtIndexPath so you can set self (the controller) as the target of the action. You can still create and position the button in IB, just don't connect its action there.

Comment: Apologies, I'm fairly new to iOS development, so I'm slightly confused, although I think I am nearly there. I realise that you mean `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method in the ViewController, and that defining the actions there whilst creating the cell would allow for the VC to perform the segue action. I don't understand how to use `addTarget:action:forControlEvents:` to achieve this though. Could you provide a snippet of what the code would like in the scenario? Any help would be great.

Comment: @Geesh_SO, [cell.button addTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside]; replace cell.button with a different reference to the button if you need to, and implement the method -(void)handleTap:(UIButton *) sender in your controller.